# Why are headers/pictures being placed beneath instead of beside?

Tags: html, css, css-position

this is for sure a noobish html question, because i am new at this stuff.

Anyways lets get to it:

1st, check the fiddle:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/d6767uur/

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<link type="text/css" href="frontpage.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body> 
<div class="navBar"> 



<div class="greyline"> </div>
<a href="smoothies_page.html" style="text-decoration: none"><div class="menu"> smoothies </div>      </a>
<div class="greyline"> </div>
<a href="milkshakes_page.html"style="text-decoration: none"><div class="menu"> milkshakes </div></a>
<div class="greyline"> </div>
<a href="juicyfacts_page.html"style="text-decoration: none"><div class="menu"> juicy facts </div></a>
<div class="greyline"> </div>
<a href="aboutus_page.html"style="text-decoration: none"><div class="menu"> about us </div></a>
<div class="greyline"> </div>
<div class="stuffwithsmall"> &copy; All rights reserved..  </div>
</div>

<div class="frontWrapper"> 
<h1> HELLO </h1>
<div style="margin-left: 750px; margin-top: -435px;"> <img src="frontfruit.jpg"> </div>



</div>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face { font-family: SourceSansPro-Regular; src: url('SourceSansPro-Regular.otf'); }

body {
margin: 0px; 
padding: 0px;


}

.navBar {
width: 205px;
height: 667px;
background-color: #55AE3A;    //hover = 398a20

}

.greyline {
width: 205px;
height: 1px;
background-color: darkgrey;
}

.menu {
font-family: 'SourceSansPro-Regular';
color: white;

font-size: 25px;
opacity: 0.64;
height: 40px;
text-decoration: none;
}

.menu:hover {
background-color: #398a20;
}


.stuffwithsmall {
color: #75715e;
font-family: helvetica;
margin-top: 320px;
}
```

Question: why is that header going down below the main menu, and how do i change it, so that it goes to the right of the menu?

Comment: Alright, alright.. Just thought it was easier for you guys to get through then... Are people getting angry of this?(tons of downvotes) It was not really my intention to "trick" or "sidestep" anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your navbar div goes down that far because .stuffwithsmall class is inside it and has a huge margin-top. You can fix that by moving it lower, after the closing tag of navbar div.

In css, change:

```
.navbar {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```